# Real life examples comparable to number of electrons in $1\rm C$

Tags: charge, atomic-physics, everyday-life, education, estimation

In order to teach 7th-grade students of the enormity of the number of electrons in 1 coulomb of charge  $$1\ {\rm C} =6.25 \times 10^{18}~ {\rm electrons}$$
I wish to compare this number to a real-life example. How may I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say this is not quite the right approach. A perhaps better illustration is to show, instead of how *big* the number is, how *not*-big it is, and yet how, despite that, it has the potential to be *extremely* impactful. Sure, you can count grains of sand and pennies and imagine big mountains of these things, but electrons are also *really really tiny*, so it's kind of pointless, I'd think - an awful huge number of equally awfully small things is... what?

Instead, we should look at how that charge compares to the bulk of material in question, and what it can do.

The number of electrons required to obtain one coulomb of charge, while huge in absolute terms, is only about

$$0.000\ 01\ \mathrm{mol}$$

of electrons. For comparison, $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ of *atoms* of copper, a common conducting material, would be about the amount of atoms in a short cylindrical segment of copper rod the size of the whole length and girth of an adult human's pinky finger. Only one in one hundred thousand of those atoms - a volume of material that now would be only but the size of a tiny grain of sand - would thus need to lose an electron to generate 1 coulomb of static charge, yet if they could, it would generate a force equal to the weight of several *battleships* on a similar object that were emplaced at a distance of one metre therefrom.

(Of course, that charge separation is infeasible to make happen in real life in that particular manner - instead, to make it go, we need to put something in place in between the two reservoirs to dampen the electric fields, i.e. a dielectric, and that makes a capacitor, and even with that, which is a mighty strong dampener, a capacitor that can hold a charge at this level is still one that stores enough energy to run a vehicle when brought to said levels.)

Comment: That is a great example, I remember having seen a similar calculation at school. Just a small comment. I think that this is only really impressive when one first has a grasp on the largeness of the number and is then humbled by other numbers being even greater.

Answer (score 3):

1. So one options is to go with the number of (dry) sand grains on earth's beaches. According to the link below, it's at $7.5 \times 10^{18}$.
   Here's the link: https://text.npr.org/161096233
2. According to the next link I dug up, there are about $3 \times 10^{13}$ cells in a human body. Did they already check cells under a microscope in 7th grade? Anyway, the number of electrons is as much as all the cells in $200,000$ people, which may roughly be the size of your town or some surrounding area. Or you go a bit bigger: Elephants seem to have about 100 times that. So you could go with rougly $2,000$ elephants.
   Link: https://www.healthline.com/health/number-of-cells-in-body.
   And another one that even does some calculations: http://www.microbehunter.com/how-many-cells-are-there-in-the-human-body/
3. Returning from beach walks and biology to physical scales, the surface area of the earth is $5 \times 10^{15}$ m$^2$. To cover that area with $6.25 \times 10^{18}$ objects, they would need to have an area of $8$ cm$^2$. Not sure about the toys of current kids, but that is of the order of magnitude of dice. If you have slightly larger dice in your school, you could just hold one of them up and let them imagine covering the earth. Or you take a lot of them and let them guess how much it takes to cover a table, to cover the classroom floor, to cover the school... and then you go to covering the planet. Depends a bit on dice size, but the order of magnitude should do.
   Link for dice sizes: https://www.dicegamedepot.com/dice-sizes/

Sorry, I got a bit lost in googling. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to count 1 electron every second, it would take you around 20 billion years, more than current age of the universe, to count all the electrons in 1 Coulomb.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to assign each electron to a coarse sand grain (1mm³ cube), they would form roughly one-mile sided cube (exactly, 1840 m).

Or, the grains could fill a decent mountain massive, perhaps more than sufficient for an one-day hiking trip.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is fantastic.  But whether in relation to electrons or anything else, I think it can be worthwhile to try to conceive of what large numbers actually represent.  It is so easy to write $10^{18}$ and so hard to visualize what it means.

It is tempting to conjure up piles of sand, as some answers here have done.  But for me anyway, the cubic relationship between the linear dimension of a pile and the number of grains in it can be misleading.  There are a billion cubic millimeters in a cubic meter (the size of a large washing machine), but if you line up those millimeter cubes side by side, they stretch 1000 km (the length of Italy).  That, I find counterintuitive, and so I avoid volume ratios for this purpose.

So, I will try to describe $N = 6.25 \times 10^{18}$ in terms of distance only, where the arithmetic is linear, and so, hopefully, more intuitive.  Take as the small distance a tenth of a millimeter, roughly the diameter of a human hair and maybe about the smallest easily visible size.  It takes $4 \times 10^{11}$ hairs laid side by side to wrap around the earth.  Lay $N$ hairs side by side, wrap the resulting strip around the equator, and start counting the wraps, one wrap per second.  Counting nonstop, it takes half a year to finish the job.